# Redshift: [08003] This connection has been closed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am using a generic IDE (JetBrains DataGrip) with Amazon Redshift.
When I don't run queries for 20-30 minutes, and return to run a query, I typically get the error message:

```
[08003] This connection has been closed.
```

After I get this error message, and immediately try running the query again, the query works.  So I gather my first failed attempt reactivates the connection, but then I have to manually rerun the query again to work.

My question: Is there a line of code/query I can insert at the top of my queries to reactivate the connection?  I want to avoid this two step manual process when running a query.

Redshift uses: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1150

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use Amazon's Redshift specific JDBC driver: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html

If you want to use the generic Postgres driver you need to set `tcpKeepAlive=true` in the Advanced options of the DataGrip connection.

Comment: Note for anyone wondering the DBeaver equivalent to this fix looks like:

1. In Database Navigator) Right-click the DB
2. Connection settings
3. Click the Driver properties (It's a tab, not submenu)
4. (Scroll to the bottom) tcpKeepAlive
5. Change to true